# Why grep search '0,^M$' return empty lines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

```
$ cat -e test.csv | grep 150463452112
65,150463452112,609848340831,2.87,126,138757585104,0,0,^M$
65,150463452112,609848340832,3.37,126,138757585105,1,0,^M$
$ grep 150463452112 test.csv   | grep '0,^M$'


$
```

I enter the '^M' with Ctrl+V Ctrl+M and need to match the line with the ending of `0,^M$'. However, the grep returns empty lines.

Question> What is the correct syntax to search the ending?

Thank you

`,0,0,` seen in hexdump is as follows:

```
2c 30 2c 30 2c 0d 0a

|,0,0,..|
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `xxd test.csv`?

Comment: @NPE Why not `hexdump -Cv test.csv` (from `bsdmainutils`)?

Comment: @iBug: Don't really mind, as long as we get to see the hex dump.

Comment: The best thing to do is get rid of the CR characters from the file before trying to process it with Unix tools. Use the `dos2unix` command to fix it.

Comment: The file was written with csv.writerow of Python function.

Comment: So you want to find `\r\n`. The `^M` is some software's way of writing `\r`, it's not the actual sequence itself (there's no `^` in your file, nor any `M`).

Comment: BTW -- does `printf '%s\r\n' '65,150463452112,609848340831,2.87,126,138757585104,0,0,'
'65,150463452112,609848340832,3.37,126,138757585105,1,0,' >test.csv` generate an output file with which all the symptoms you're describing can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that your file *doesn't actually contain* any two-character `^M` sequence (and even if it did, `^` is special to regex and doesn't match itself). Rather, it contains a carriage return before its final linefeed (being a DOS-style rather than UNIX-style text file). What you want to match is not a `^M` sequence but a literal carriage return.

---

One way to do this is to pass `grep` a shell literal using bash and ksh `$''` C-style string literal syntax:

```
grep $'0,\r$'
```

...which you can test as follows:

```
## test function: generate two lines with CRLFs, one "hello world", the other "foo,0,"
$ generate_sample_data() { printf '%s\r\n' 'hello world' 'foo,0,'; }

## demonstrate that we have 0d 0a line endings on the output from this function
$ generate_sample_data | hexdump -C
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f  72 6c 64 0d 0a 66 6f 6f  |hello world..foo|
00000010  2c 30 2c 0d 0a                                    |,0,..|
00000015

## demonstrate that the given grep matches only the line ending in "0," before the CRLF
$ generate_sample_data | egrep $'0,\r$'
foo,0,
```

Comment: `grep 150463452112 test.csv | grep $'0,\r$' | wc -l` returns 3. However, the output results from the terminal are three empty lines.

Comment: @q0987, then you have other control codes not given in your sample output overwriting that content or making it invisible. Try `grep 150463452112 test.csv | grep $'0,\r$' | cat -e` -- and make sure the question includes everything necessary to reproduce the bug, **including** the behavior described in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed [here](https://superuser.com/a/453606/450332), escape characters for color highlighting might be interfering with the `^M` character.

You probably have *grep* aliased to `grep --color=auto` or something similar. Use `\grep` or `grep --color=never`.

```
$ grep 150463452112 test.csv | \grep '0,^M$'
65,150463452112,609848340831,2.87,126,138757585104,0,0,
65,150463452112,609848340832,3.37,126,138757585105,1,0,
```

With `^M` entered with **Ctrl+V Ctrl+M**.

Comment: Just noticed the `-e` option in `cat`. That's not a literal `^M`, it's a CR character being shown as an escape sequence.

Comment: And `$` is the end of line, not literal.

Comment: `grep 150463452112 test.csv   | grep '0,$'` or `grep 150463452112 test.csv   | grep '0,\$'` Return empty lines.

Comment: @pacholik, which vendor's implementation of `grep` is this where you tested `'0,^M$'` to match a line with a CRLF?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy GNU Grep. It's just `^M` was entered with **Ctrl+V Ctrl+M** just like OP did.

Comment: Ahh -- as a literal, yes, that would work. That said, you could express that in a way that would be amenable to copy-and-paste.

Comment: BTW, `grep --color=auto` doesn't produce color escape sequences when its stdout isn't to a TTY, and a pipeline (obvs.) isn't a TTY.